# Inconsistant Bar sizes in matplotlib graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

***Disregard this question: The problem was I was not giving zeros and holding dates in the lists to produce the graph. Without the dates holding zeros matplotlib correctly tried to span to fill the space. What I need to do is build a function to fill in missing dates or feed the missing dates in the original call.

Good Graph:

[image: good graph]
<sub>(source: [warfightercoffeeshop.com](https://www.warfightercoffeeshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/HMC.png))</sub>

Bad Graph:

[image: good graph]

I have a hard to sort through problem. I am trying to create a lot of consistent graphs and put together a matplotlib class to handle the problem. All works well and I usually have consistent outputs. But in cases where the x axis does not have data points at all dates I get really wide bars. I will try and post pictures, but my reputation is an issue.

Does anyone know how to call to see if the axis size has changed? It is all relative to the x size so if I can figure it out relative to the number of x entries it may work? Any help would be appreciated.

The code for calling is below:

```
test_chart = HPM_Chart_Gen_class.HPM_Graph(x, title, "Date", "Hours", is_date=True, span_dates = False)
test_chart.add_y_axis(y2, "Spindle Hours", type="bar", trendline=False, datalables=True)
test_chart.add_y_axis(y, "Billable Hours", type="bar", trendline=False, datalables=True)

test_chart.print_chart(r'M:\ZZ_Continuous Improvement\Dashboard_Pictures\\' + current + r'.png')
```

And the class:

```
class new_y_axis:

    def __init__(self, data, label, type, trendline, datalables):
        #type can be bar
        self.type = type
        self.data = data
        self.label = label
        self.trendline = trendline
        self.datalables = datalables


class HPM_Graph:

    def __init__(self, x_axis, title, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, width=15, height=10, fontsize=12, is_date = False, span_dates = False):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fontsize = fontsize
        self.x_axis_label = x_axis_label
        self.y_axis_label = y_axis_label
        self.x_axis = x_axis
        self.is_date = False
        self.y_axis = []
        self.multiple_bar = False
        #this colors list is the maximum y values available, you should never go over this
        self.colors_list = ['#5DA5DA', '#FAA43A', '#60BD68', '#F15854',  '#B2912F', '#DECF3F','#B276B2', '#29aeec', '#e3b02e', '#024d6a', '#b45757', '#fb0933', '#96c71c', '#b9aaee', '#801a42', '#e56297', '#01e0f4', '#d0aa1c']
        self.is_date = is_date
        self.title = title
        self.span_dates = span_dates
        self.x_axis_is_string = False
        self.x_axis_is_string_labels = []
        self.test_x_axis_for_strings()
        self.number_of_bars = 0
    
    def add_y_axis(self, data, label,type="plot",trendline=False, datalables=True):
        self.y_axis.append(new_y_axis(data,label,type,trendline,datalables))
        if type == "bar":
            self.number_of_bars=self.number_of_bars+1
    
    def print_chart(self, save_path):
        self.width_interval_to_use = 1
        matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': self.fontsize})
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(self.width,self.height))
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        axis_count_bar = 0
        if self.is_date == True:
            #we need to see if this is a date range and split accordingly - has to be done before dates are turned into float
            self.x_axis = date2num(self.x_axis)
            self.formatter = DateFormatter('%m-%d-%y')        
            # self.ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
            days = mdates.DayLocator()  # every month
            self.ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
            self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(self.formatter)
        if self.x_axis_is_string == True:
            print(self.x_axis_is_string_labels)
            self.ax.set_xticklabels(self.x_axis_is_string_labels)
            self.ax.tick_params(width=2)
        self.ax.set_xticks(self.x_axis, minor=True)
        self.axis_ittirator()
        self.ax.legend(loc=0)
        self.ax.set_title(self.title)
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.ax.set_xlabel(self.x_axis_label)
        self.ax.set_ylabel(self.y_axis_label)
        self.figure.autofmt_xdate()
        self.figure.savefig(save_path)
        print(save_path)
    
    def autolabel(self, rects):
        for rect in rects:
            height = rect.get_height()
            self.ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.02*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
        
    def axis_ittirator(self):
        self.multiple_bar = True
        #margin gen sets the bar width as 80% at all times
        margin_gen = 0.8
        self.bar_width = margin_gen/self.number_of_bars
        self.bar_index = -(margin_gen/2)
        for current_y_axis in self.y_axis:
           color = self.colors_list[0]
           self.colors_list.remove(color)
           if current_y_axis.trendline == True:
                z = np.polyfit(self.x_axis, current_y_axis.data, 1)
                py1 = np.poly1d(z)
                label_string = f"{current_y_axis.label} trend"
                color_string = f"--"
                self.ax.plot(self.x_axis,py1(self.x_axis), "--", color=color, label=label_string)
            if current_y_axis.type == "bar":
                # add = self.bar_index-0.5
                add = self.bar_index
                temp_x_axis = [x+add for x in self.x_axis]
                print(f"adding {add} for index {self.bar_index}")
                resection = self.ax.bar(temp_x_axis,current_y_axis.data, align="edge", color=f"{color}", width=self.bar_width, label=current_y_axis.label)
                self.bar_index = self.bar_index + self.bar_width 
            else:
                self.ax.plot(self.x_axis,current_y_axis.data, color=f"{color}", label=current_y_axis.label)
            if current_y_axis.datalables == True:
                self.autolabel(resection)
            
    def test_x_axis_for_strings(self):
        for current_x_axis_value in self.x_axis:
            if isinstance(current_x_axis_value, str):
                self.x_axis_is_string = True
        if self.x_axis_is_string:
            self.is_date = False
            Axis_holder = copy.deepcopy(self.x_axis)
            self.x_axis = []
            self.i = 0
            for current_heald_x_axis_value in Axis_holder:
                self.i = self.i+1
                self.x_axis.append(self.i)
                self.x_axis_is_string_labels.append(current_heald_x_axis_value)
```

Comment: Will post pictures as soon as I have reputation - off to look for questions to answer!

Comment: You can upload them somewhere (Imgur) and link them. An editor can add them for you.

Comment: I have to get 10 reputation. I have them posted to my site and ready to go.

Comment: Then just link them in a comment. I can add them in for you.

Comment: Good Graph: https://www.warfightercoffeeshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/HMC.png

Comment: Bad Graph: https://www.warfightercoffeeshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/MU-5-AXIS.png

Another bad Graph: https://www.warfightercoffeeshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/MU6300.png

Comment: Disregard: I was pulling data incorrectly - Thank you for helping with the picture issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this question: The problem was I was not giving zeros and holding dates in the lists to produce the graph. Without the dates holding zeros matplotlib correctly tried to span to fill the space. What I need to do is build a function to fill in missing dates or feed the missing dates in the original call.